# How to install local NPM module and it's dependencies to project?

Tags: npm, dependencies, npm-install, eslint

I'm working on shareable `eslint` configuration to spread automation and internal best-practices. So I'm adding some eslint plugins and tools as dependencies.

### Context

#### Env

```
$ node --version; 
v8.2.1

$ npm --version
5.3.0
```

#### Local package

To do so I created a local `npm` project, says `eslint-config-company`, with the following `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "eslint-config-company",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "4.x.x",
    "eslint-plugin-ember-suave": "1.x.x",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "2.x.x",
    "prettier": "1.x.x"
  },
  "files": [
    "index.js"
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "eslint",
    "eslintconfig"
  ],
  "repository": "company/eslint-config-company",
  "private": true
}
```

and files:

```
index.js  package.json  README.md  yarn.lock
```

#### Installing

Then, I install my `eslint-config-company` package into a another project to test it:

```
npm install --save-dev --verbose ../eslint-config-company
```

In `node_modules/` directory I got the `eslint-config-company/` as a symlink:

```
$ ls node_modules/eslint-config-company -lah
lrwxrwxrwx 1 me me 29 Aug 17 22:02 node_modules/eslint-config-company -> ../../eslint-config-company/
```

but no trace of either `prettier` nor `eslint-plugin-prettier`

```
$ ls node_modules/{prettier,eslint-plugin-prettier}
ls: cannot access 'node_modules/prettier': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'node_modules/eslint-plugin-prettier': No such file or directory
```

N.B.: `eslint` and `eslint-plugin-ember-suave` are already dependencies of that project thus exists.

### Question

- Am I wrong assuming that my package's `dependencies` will install on `npm install` ?
- How do I fix my package in order to install them?

**related:** [issue on npm/npm](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18228)

Answer (score 0):

The eslint-config-company's dependencies are held in that module's node_modules folder - so it will be able to find the code it needs via the symlink (assuming npm install has been run on the eslint-config-company module folder).

When packaged up - the node_module folder is included as well, so it translates up to delivery time as well.

Answer (score -1):

Create global module of your project **eslint-config-company** (in this module folder):

```
npm link
```

and links the global installation target in another project whit :

```
npm link eslint-config-company
```

*source : https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link*

Comment: Doing that is just an indirect symlink the `eslint-config-company` (going through a global repository), there is no installation of dependencies here.